# React Function Component use variable (not state)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With React Class Component, I use some variable (not `this.state`) helping my control logic. Example: `this.isPressBackspace = false` and when I set variable don't make component re-render (ex: `this.isPressBackspace = true`).

That's working perfect in Class Component but when I change to Function Component, **I dont know where to place `this.isPressBackspace`**.

Here is my example in codesandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/function-component-example-3h98d

Comment: Did you try to use [Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) instead?

Comment: You have to use useState and modify the state Here I have converted your code take a look. https://codesandbox.io/s/function-component-example-forked-0fkl3

Comment: @DipankarMaikap thank, but I dont want use useState. Do you know other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

```js
const isPressBackspaceRef = React.useRef(false);
const keyDownPositionRef = React.useRef({});
const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    // this is wrong syntax
    // this.keyDownPosition OR let keyDownPosition
    keyDownPositionRef.current = {
      start: e.target.selectionStart,
      end: e.target.selectionEnd
    };
    switch (e.key) {
      case "Backspace":
        isPressBackspaceRef.current = true; // this is wrong syntax ????
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  };
const onChange = (e) => {
    const { end } = keyDownPositionRef;
    if (isPressBackspaceRef.current) {
      const length = end - e.target.selectionEnd;
      alert(`You delete ${length} character`);
    }
    isPressBackspaceRef.current = false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience you don't use the this keyword when working with function components. Instead you use hooks like useState.
Check the following video for getting started with hooks:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O6P86uwfdR0&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified